# Statement with no effect with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, compiler-warnings

I have 2 structs using pointers to form a linked list and I'm creating operations that work over these types:

```
typedef struct hashtag { 
    char *text;
    int count;
} *Item;

typedef struct node {
    Item item;
    struct node *next;
} *link;
```

I'm having a couple issues with pointers all on the same function.

```
/* adds hashtag (Item Type) to linked list (Link Type) */

void add_hashtag(char *word){
    int search_result, i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)

     /* converts word to all lowercase before adding */

    token[i]=tolower(*(token + i));
    Item buffer = (Item) malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
    strcpy(buffer->text,word);

    /* Runs through the list to see if the hashtag was already added */

    search_result = (search_hashtag(head, buffer));
    if (search_result!=NULL){

        /* Increase count (occurrence) of hashtag if it already exists (returns link type or NULL if not found) */

        increase_hashtag_count(search_result);
    }

    /* Create new struct type hashtag */
    new_hashtag(buffer);

}
```

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>     search_result = (search_hashtag(head, buffer));
>
> warning: comparison between pointer and integer
>     if (search_result!=NULL){

The `tolower()` function and `search_result()` are not working with pointers correctly and I'm having trouble debugging this.

edit: `tolower()` fixed, I misread the documentation

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `int search_result` but It has been required that a pointer. `strcpy(buffer->text,word);`  : `buffer->text` does not allocated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in the function.

First of all it is not clear what is variable `token`and where and how it is declared, used, and set

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)

 /* converts word to all lowercase before adding */

token[i]=tolower(*(token + i));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is desirable to check that a call to malloc was successfull. For example

```
Item buffer = (Item) malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
if ( buffer )
{
    //...other stuff
}
```

The memory for buffer->text was not allocated. So this statement

```
strcpy(buffer->text,word);
```

has undefined behaviour.

Variable `search_result` is declared as having type `int`. You should to compare it with an integer instead of a pointer

```
search_result = (search_hashtag(head, buffer));
if (search_result!=NULL){
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems that if hashtag already exists you should not add a new hashtag to the list in this statement

```
new_hashtag(buffer);
```

It is enough to increase the count (occurrence) of the existed hashtag.

Comment: Very good help, thanks a lot!  Regarding the buffer->text allocation can you elucidate me a bit more? By using 'Item buffer = (Item) malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));' am I not allocating memory for both the Item.count and Item.text variables?

Also regarding the search_hashtag(), it returns NULL if it's not already found. So != NULL = new_hashtag();

But Im not so sure as how to call the function properly with pointers

Comment: @spacing struct hashtag  has two data members count and pointer text that will point to the string word as I understand. So you need to allocate memory for a copy of word. For example  buffer->text = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 ); . As for the function serach_hashtag then you should determine what return type it has.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower) of `tolower()`,

> The value returned is that of the converted letter, or `c` if the conversion was not possible.

That means, it does not *change* the passed argument, it `return`s the result as the function call return value and in your case, you are ignoring the return value, making the whole function call pointless.

So, you need to have another array to store the return value of `tolower()` to get the converted lowercase *string*.

That said, for the second case, you have defined `search_result` as `int` but later, you're trying to compare it against `NULL`, which is a null-pointer constant. You need to correct the data type accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I completely misread the docs somehow, I've fixed that issues now but the other issues with search results still persist

Comment: @spacing: so what issues remain? You only say that they 'are not working correctly'.

Comment: @RadLexus (search_hashtag)/search_result() is not working properly with the same errors of the main post